# Error with urllib3 when launching azure webapp

Tags: azure, flask, web-hosting, chunks, urllib3

I am trying to host my Flask application on azure. To do this I followed [this tutorial on hosting flask app on azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli) (I also used the sample application given in the tutorial). I then run the command:

```cs
az webapp up --runtime PYTHON:3.9 --sku B1 --logs
```

but get the following message:

```cs
`The webapp 'witty-coast-99cdf44e87c541d492a413bb27936a7c' doesn't exist
Creating AppServicePlan 'eivindkjosbakken_asp_1275' ...
Creating webapp 'witty-coast-99cdf44e87c541d492a413bb27936a7c' ...
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
Creating zip with contents of dir C:\Users\eivin\Documents\Programming\msdocs-python-flask-webapp-quickstart ...
Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
You can launch the app at http://witty-coast-99cdf44e87c541d492a413bb27936a7c.azurewebsites.net
Configuring default logging for the app, if not already enabled
2023-09-05T13:39:46  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
Exception in thread Thread-1 (_get_log):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 761, in _update_chunk_length
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b''
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```cs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 444, in _error_catcher
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 828, in read_chunked
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 765, in _update_chunk_length
urllib3.exceptions.InvalidChunkLength: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```cs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 953, in run
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\azure/cli/command_modules/appservice/custom.py", line 2852, in _get_log
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 624, in stream
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 816, in read_chunked
  File "contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
  File "D:\a\_work\1\s\build_scripts\windows\artifacts\cli\Lib\site-packages\urllib3/response.py", line 461, in _error_catcher
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read)", InvalidChunkLength(got length b'', 0 bytes read))`
```

I see that this is an issue mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25599), but they had no solution there and nothing else has been mentioned.

My question is then, does anyone know how to fix this (even a temporary solution would be highly appreciated).

Azure CLI version: 2.52.0.

Running pip list after installing the packages from requirements.txt:
click        8.1.7
colorama     0.4.6
Flask        2.0.2
gunicorn     21.2.0
itsdangerous 2.1.2
Jinja2       3.1.2
MarkupSafe   2.1.3
packaging    23.1
pip          23.1.2
setuptools   65.5.0
Werkzeug     2.3.7

I have tried several things: Not specifying Python version in the az webapp up command (does not help). I have also tried clearing the cache with az cache purge". I am thinking that if I could change the code in the urllib3 package that azure is using, then I could potentially find a temporary solution, but I am unsure how to change this package (as it is a package azure uses automatically when running az webapp up)

Comment: Try to run the az webapp up with `az webapp up -n MyUniqueAppName --runtime PYTHON:3.9 --sku B1 --logs` and check once.

Comment: Provide the name of webapp and run the command

Comment: Do you have `response.py` in your code? If yes, make sure it is build without any errors.

Comment: I tried running with name as you said and it gives the same error message. response.py is a file in the urllib3 package, but it seems like Azure adds this package automatically (as it is not a package I have in my virtual environment as you can see from my pip list command in the question)

Comment: Ok..will try from my end and let you know.

Comment: I found that if I use Azure CLI version 2.23.0 the sample application works, though this still is not a proper fix for the problem in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed the same MS Doc which you have provided.

Initially even I got the same error.

[image]

Run `az cache purge` in the root directory of the App which you have cloned from GitHub.

[image]

- Now the Web App has been created and uploaded the files successfully.
- You can see the Log Stream of the running app.

[image]

[image]

***Az CLI Version***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

Comment: hmm, I tried following your exact procedure, but I still get the same error when using Azure CLI version 2.52.0. I see that you are using Linux (while I am using Windows), perhaps the issue could lie there?

Comment: May be..Once try with the linux env..

Comment: @Kjosbakken - Are you facing issue with Linux environment as well ?

Comment: Nop, it works there!

Comment: @Kjosbakken - Within the same Doc which you are following , you can see that - Python in [Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRAkr.png) is no longer supported.May be that is the reason you are unable to run in windows. Any how we can see that same is working in Linux app.

Comment: Yes, the solution was very helpful! The solution is accepted now!